# Break servlet-filter work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I have `SecurityAuthorisationFilter` and the following part of the code:

```
for(String anonymousRequestURI : anonymousRequestURIs) {
     if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(anonymousRequestURI)) {
         //allow request
     }
 }
 String authToken = getTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
```

If equals is true I need to skip all next filter operations and send request to controller. But, if I write `filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse)`, there is no result. The filter continue operations to find a token. How can I break out of the filter?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to skip the rest of the filter chain or just stop this filter?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I want to stop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from your comment, you wish to "break out" of the current filter if the condition about anonymous request URI is true. You could simply `return;` after calling `chain.doFilter()`:

```
for ( String uri : anonURIs ) {
    if ( ... ) {
        chain.doFilter( ... );
        return;
    }
}

String authToken = getTokenFromRequest( httpRequest );
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. Now `chain.doFilter( ... );` is working...interesting...how, if earlier it didn't work? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if `break`doesn't give you what you need you can change your loop like this:

```
int i=0;
do {
      anonymousRequestURI = anonymousRequestURIs[i];
      i++;
while(!httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(anonymousRequestURI) && i<anonymousRequestURIs.length);
String authToken = getTokenFromRequest(httpRequest);
```

Comment: No, it only breaks for loop and continue try to get authToken.

Comment: @Squeez well change your loop like tin my EDIT.

Comment: I neet to break out from filter and send request to controller if equals is true.